# Is there any way to make the image clickable, to get redirected to other asp.net page?

Tags: html, asp.net

How can I make the image clickable so I can be redirected to other asp net page?

```
<div class="banner-section spad">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="single-banner">
                    <img src="img/banner-1.jpg">
                    <div class="inner-text">
                        <h4>Homem</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just wrap image into anchor tag

```html
<div class="banner-section spad">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="single-banner">
                    <a href="http:://yoururl"><img src="img/banner-1.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="inner-text">
                        <h4>Homem</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is the issue. can you please post updated code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="banner-section spad">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="single-banner">
                <a href="https://URL"><img src="img/banner-1.jpg"></a>
                <div class="inner-text">
                    <h4>Homem</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```